# Trouble with Euclidean distance statement

Tags: python

Write a function named "distance" that takes two floating point numbers as parameters representing the (x, y) coordinates of a point in a 2d space. Define your distance method to return the Euclidean distance between the input point and the point (14.9, 16.2)

```
import math
def distance(x, y):
     return (((x - 14.9) ** 2) + ((y - 16.2) ** 2))** 1/2
```

Comment: Please, specify the error you are having next time you ask a question. Many could guess that the error comes from the order of operation of your exponent, but you might not be as lucky next time.

Answer (score 0):

Following should do.

```
import math
def distance(x,y):
    return math.sqrt((x - 14.9)**2 + (y - 16.2)**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
def distance(x, y):
     return (((x - 14.9) ** 2) + ((y - 16.2) ** 2))**0.5
```

This should work or another alternative would be

```
import math
def distance(x, y):
     return (((x - 14.9) ** 2) + ((y - 16.2) ** 2))**(1/2)
```

The mistake in your code is that it is applied as
**(expression^1)/2** and not **expression^(1/2)**